# Hibernate do not include child entities of same type as entity in list of another entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have two entities, `Menu` and `MenuItem`, as showed in the source code below. I'm trying to get the Menu with all child entities from the database, but Hibernate is also inserting the child entities of a MenuItem in the `nodes` list of the `Menu` entity.

Menu.java

```java
[...]

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "menu", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("order ASC")
    private List<MenuItem> nodes = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
[...]
```

MenuItem.java

```java
[...]

    @ManyToOne
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
    private MenuItem parentItem;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parentItem", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<MenuItem> children = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "menuId")
    private Menu menu;
[...]
```

As a hint: I know you should not use FetchType.EAGER for collections, but as I need all elements of the collections, it is useful to load them when the Menu is loaded. The Menu won't be used without the lists.

Comment: Could you add "picture" how you want to see your database? That would be really helpful to answer your question,  as in your question you are making ManyToOne relation inside one class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only MenuItems that are expected to be direct descendands of the `Menu` should have `menu` field set, otherwise all of them will be fetched to the `nodes` collection because of `mappedBy = "menu"`.

btw, as far as your use case for EAGER fetch type seems justified, you should not use EAGER fetching in general, not only on collections. [This is a good read about the topic](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/).

Comment: Okay, how can I load all the collections using HQL, especially when the MenuItem have child MenuItems, and then they have also a collection of MenuItems, like a tree?

Comment: HQL does not support recursive queries, so unless your database supports recursive queries and you are willing to use native query (or create view?), you would need additional field on `MenuItem` which would reference `Menu` and set it on every MenuItem. For example, `menu` field would be set only for direct descendants of the menu (first level of the menu), and `root` field would be set for all descendants.

Answer (score 0):

CascadeType.ALL will propagate (cascade) all EntityManager operations to the relating entities.

Try to remove `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` from relation.

By default, no operations are cascaded.